# How to add a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an additional text area so I need to duplicate part of this code but I am not sure which part.
Can anyone please help?

```
function mode_add_message()
{
jQuery("#editor").hide();
jQuery("#cropper").hide();
jQuery("#crop_preview_container").hide();

jQuery("#pxn8_canvas").show();
jQuery("#messages").empty();

jQuery("#edit_and_crop").show();
jQuery("#add_text").show("slow");

gAddTextOpNumber = PXN8.opNumber;

if (gCardDB[gActiveCard].text_placeholders){
    var placeholders = gCardDB[gActiveCard].text_placeholders;
    for (var i = 0;i < placeholders.length; i++){
        var text = placeholders[i];
        var html = "";
        if (text.multiline){
            html = "<li><textarea name=\"text_" + i + "\" id=\"text_" + i + "\">Message # "    +        (i+1) + " Here</textarea></li>";
        }else{
            html = "<li><input class=\"text\" type=\"text\" name=\"text_" + i + "\" id=\"text_" + i + "\" value=\"Message # " + (i+1) + " here\"></li>";
        }
        jQuery(html).appendTo("#messages");
    }
    }else{
    end_cardmaker();
    }
    }
//

// There can be multiple text inputs/textareas so each must be added.
```

This is the URL: http://pixenate.com/pixenate/themes/cardmaker/index.php

Comment: `if (text.multiline){
            html = "<li><textarea name=\"text_" + i + "\" id=\"text_" + i + "\">Message # "    +        (i+1) + " Here</textarea></li>";
        }` this part creates a text area

Answer (score 0):

This part of code will help you adding textarea:

```
 if (gCardDB[gActiveCard].text_placeholders){
        var placeholders = gCardDB[gActiveCard].text_placeholders;
        for (var i = 0;i < placeholders.length; i++){
            var text = placeholders[i];
            var html = "";
            if (text.multiline){
                html = "<li><textarea name=\"text_" + i + "\" id=\"text_" + i + "\">Message # "    +        (i+1) + " Here</textarea></li>";
            }else{
                html = "<li><input class=\"text\" type=\"text\" name=\"text_" + i + "\" id=\"text_" + i + "\" value=\"Message # " + (i+1) + " here\"></li>";
            }
            jQuery(html).appendTo("#messages");
         }
   }else{
        end_cardmaker();
   }
```

but I'm not sure what those conditions are for, as I haven't had a look at your whole code. Just to add a textarea will be:

```
var html = '<li><textarea name="" id="">Message #1 Here</textarea></li>';
jQuery(html).appendTo("#messages");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems like there is something in this code that adds another text box automatically each time a text placeholder is added to the js file. When I added a text box with the code you gave me another one is also added. How would I cancel that and just add the code you gave? The reason that I want to do that is to control what is written in the text box because it automatically adds Message # 1 Here, Message # 2 Here, etc to each box and if I use your code then I can change the text in the box. (I hope my question is clear)

Comment: Can you put your code to jsfiddle so that I can take a look at it?